# Setting the controlsource value of a listbox using Properties Window

Tags: forms, vba, excel, listbox

I am new to VBA and am currently still studying the most basic ideas of the language. I haven't gotten that far in my VBA Code studies to write the code I need by hand, so, in the mean time, I have been using the VBA Editor to enter Property Values via the Properties Window. This has been proving far more difficult than I anticipated. My Goal is to create a drop down list for a VBA Form. I understand one of my options is to reference a range of cells in my excel worksheet by inputting it into the value field located right of the ControlSource Property. My attempts to input the desired range always comes up with the same error:

**Could not set the ControlSource Property. Invalid Property Value.**

I have tried looking in the VBA Help files and even searched online. I haven't had any luck finding the proper syntax to enter into this field.

I am assuming I may run into similar issues as I try to set other property values through the Property Window. Thus, I am diligently studying my VBA courses so I can simply write the raw code. But that takes time and I need this form to work as soon as possible.

Is there anyone out there that wouldn't mind lending me their brain for a moment? I would be most grateful. Having this working would bring a lot of stress off of me.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you provide examples of the values that you have tried to enter?

Comment: Instead of ControlSource, can you enter the desired range of cells in the RowSource property? And make sure you use the = symbol, like so: `=sheet1!$a$1:$a$10`

Comment: thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed. The data was located on a sheet called Menu. I entered the code as =Menu!$P2:$P$36 and magically my list appeared in the drop down. Thanks!

Comment: Darn, I don't have enough reputation to vote for you. Please Rep me up so I can appreciate people more. :) and thanks again!

Comment: Glad it works out for you :-)

Comment: This no longer works in Excel. Tested to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tigeravatar mentioned, works fine for me, for the ComboBox as well for the ListBox.

If I enter `=a1:b5` into the ComboBox' RowSource, I see the values of the cells if I open the form and the Combobox. Tigeravatar's notation with `$` and `sheet!` may be more reliable for the productive version.

The RowSource is where the boxes get their displayed items from. The ControlSource is where the chosen value finally is linked to. So if I write just `A10` to the ControlSource, then open the form, then pick a value, close the form, I see the chosen value filled to the Excelsheet field A10.

Sometimes it helps to start a fresh UserForm and to add some simple fresh controls. If you seek around, you will probably alter property values that influence the behaviour in an unexpected way, and then you get lost. I have tested with Office 2010. If you have another version, it may be important to forum readers to know.